# How to list keys/values in BDB from c++

Tags: c++, database, berkeley-db

The C++ API for Berkeley DB seems straightforward enough except I can't find how to just list all the contained key/value pairs.  Did I miss this in the docs ?  Does anybody have an example ?

I read the official Berkeley DB docs.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a database cursor.  Think of it as a needle on a record, or indeed, as a cursor on the screen in a text editor.  You set up a key that describes where the database should drop the needle (the cursor).  You then move the cursor forward or backward through the records, retrieving each one in turn.

There's an example in the tutorial section of the BDB Reference Guide for the C API that shows how to open a cursor and walk through the database with `c_get`: https://docs.oracle.com/database/bdb181/html/programmer_reference/am_cursor.html#am_curget

Once you see how it's done in C, you'll be able to translate it to the C++ API.

Comment: Thanks, I  was just beginning to consider if a cursor was the solution. And it was. Problem solved.